MWE works, but quiz doesn't. How is a difference in environment changing the outcome?
I have two files, was going to post an MWE but made it work.
I have tried to find the difference between the MWE and the original, and all I can see is that I created a new (ultra-simple) quiz environment for the quiz, and the MWE uses article.
Here is the working MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz} % Include TikZ package for drawing
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\newwrite\ansfile
\immediate\openout\ansfile=\jobname.ans

\newcounter{questioncount}
\newcounter{anscount}
\setcounter{questioncount}{0}
\setcounter{anscount}{0}

\NewDocumentCommand{\q}{m}{%
  \stepcounter{questioncount}%
  \setcounter{anscount}{0}%
  \typeout{q: \arabic{questioncount}}%
  \noindent\textbf{\arabic{questioncount}. (#1 pts) }%
}    

\NewDocumentCommand{\ans}{O{72} O{36} O{}}{%
  \zsaveposx{\thequestioncount-\theanscount-x}%
  \zsaveposy{\thequestioncount-\theanscount-y}%
  \def\w{#1}%
  \def\h{#2}%
  \def\anstype{#3}%
  \fbox{\makebox(\w pt,\h pt){}}%
  \immediate\write\ansfile{\number\value{questioncount}_\number\value{anscount} %
    \the\numexpr\zposx{\thequestioncount-\theanscount-x}/65536\relax\space%
    \the\numexpr\zposy{\thequestioncount-\theanscount-y}/65536\relax\space%
    \w\space \h\space \anstype \space}%
  \stepcounter{anscount}%
}

\begin{document}
\q{0}Name: \ans[144] NetID: \ans[72] \\
\q{3}What is 2+2? \ans[72]
     How about 2+2.1? \ans[72][30][fn] \\
\q{5}What is 2+2? \ans[72][30]     \\
\q{5}What is 2+2? \ans[72][40][fn] \\
\q{10} Evaluate $\int_a^b{x^2 + 3x + 1} dx =$ \ans[144] 
\end{document}

Here is the stdquiz.tex file that I include:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz} % Include TikZ package for drawing
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\newboolean{showpoints}
\newcounter{questioncount}
\newcommand{\q}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{questioncount}%
    \setcounter{anscount}{0}%
    \par\medskip\noindent\textbf{\arabic{questioncount}.} %
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{showpoints}}{ (#1 points)}{}%
    \quad%
}

\newcounter{anscount}

%
% create a box for an answer with a specified width and height
% a separate answer file is created to store the locations
% of the answers for automatic grading
% the answer file is in the format:
% questionnumber.answernumber x y width height correct
% x, y, width, height are in points
% the correct is the correct answer
%

\NewDocumentCommand{\ans}{O{72} O{36} O{}}{%
  \zsaveposx{\thequestioncount-\theanscount-x}%
  \zsaveposy{\thequestioncount-\theanscount-y}%
  \def\w{#1}%
  \def\h{#2}%
  \def\anstype{#3}%
  \fbox{\makebox(\w pt,\h pt){}}%
  \immediate\write\ansfile{\number\value{questioncount}_\number\value{anscount} %
    \the\numexpr\zposx{\thequestioncount-\theanscount-x}/65536\relax\space%
    \the\numexpr\zposy{\thequestioncount-\theanscount-y}/65536\relax\space%
    \w\space \h\space \anstype \space}%
  \stepcounter{anscount}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tf}{O{}}{%
\fbox{\makebox(10 pt,10 pt){}}true
\fbox{\makebox(10 pt,10 pt){}}false
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mc}{O{} O{} O{} O{}}{%
A.{#1} B.{#2} C.{#3} D.{#4}
}

\newcommand{\mcv}[4]{%
\textcircled{} #1 \\
\textcircled{} #2 \\
\textcircled{} #3 \\
\textcircled{} #4 \\
}

\newcommand{\ansbox}[2]{%
  \fbox{\makebox(#2pt,#1pt){}}
}

\graphicspath{ {img/} {figs} }

% Define the quiz environment
\newenvironment{quiz}[2]{%
\newwrite\ansfile
\immediate\openout\ansfile=\jobname.ans
\begin{flushleft}
  \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
    \multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=40pt]{img/rulogo.png}}    &   &    & \small{Name} & \small{NetID} & \small{Section} \\
         & #1 & #2 & \ans[][162] & \ans[][50] & \ans \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{flushleft}
\hrule
\setcounter{questioncount}{0}
\setcounter{anscount}{0}
%\setboolean{showpoints}{true}
}{%
\immediate\closeout\ansfile
}

mwe2 brings in the stdquiz.tex file:
\input{stdquiz.tex}

\begin{document}
\begin{quiz}{ECExxx}{Test}
Use the following picture for this quiz:
\q{10} What is 2+2? \ans
\q{10} What is 2+2? \ans
 
\end{quiz}
\end{document}

The error is:
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
Overfull \vbox (14.63072pt too high) detected at line 4
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.4 \begin{quiz}{ECExxx}{Test}

Before adding the NewCommand to stdquiz, it was working. So whatever the problem is, it should not be the other parts of the code, unless a character inadvertently was edited.
All I understand is that something is expecting a number, but I don't see where.
Both programs are compiled using pdflatex
When successful, it must be compiled twice in order for the references to be filled in correctly.

If I comment out \usepackage{zref-savepos} it mostly works (except for the missing img/rulogo.png).

@JohnKormylo but the zref package was necessary in order to get it to evaluate at the right time.
If I use \immediate\write then the coordinates are not yet available.
If I use \write then the question numbers come out all 4, because by that time, the questionnum variable is 4. How can you make the code work without zref-savepos?

The error was package not found.  I had to comment it out.  \pdfsavepos is supported by pdflatex.
